# How to solve name clash have the same erasure?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I have this problem by this moment, I got a class with two methods with the same erasure:

```
public class VO implements Map<String,String> , Serializable{

    public synchronized String put (Object key, Object value){

       if (key == null)

           return null;

       if (value == null)
           return remove(key);
       String stringKey = key.toString();

       String stringValue = value.toString();

       if (value instanceof Boolean)
            stringValue = ((Boolean)value) ? "Y" : "N";

       return put(stringKey,stringValue);
}

@Override
public synchronized String put (String key, String value)
{
    if (key == null)
        return null;
    if (value == null)
        return remove(key);
    //
    int index = m_keys.indexOf(key);
    if (index != -1)
        return m_values.set(index, value);
    m_keys.add(key);
    m_values.add(value);
    return null;
   }    //  put
 }
```

Both methods are used by this app a lot, I can't change the name of any and I can't delete `put(Object key, Object value)` method, any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: `put(Object key, Object value)` doesn't make sense in that class? Why do you have it there? Why can't you remove it?

Comment: I don't think so there is a way out. Because the first method is more general than the second method. It encompasses all the possible polymorphism calls except the primitive data types.

Comment: Downvoting this. The question is way too general and the code provided is incorrect. First of all why are you attempting to implement the `Map` interface on your own? Secondly the actual implementation is wrong. Assuming that this is the code you have at the moment, this is an incomplete implementation of `Map`. What are you trying to achieve? Please update your original question.

Comment: @BheshGurung i can't delete that put method because is used in almost 70 other classes of this application and others class that by now are in jar dependencies that i don't have access and VO is a core class that someone else created.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex yes that is just a fragment of the class but i don't think is necessary put the class complete because the problem is just that two methods have erasure problems, i don't created that class some else did it and is that way, VO is a core class and if i change something is have to be a minimal change...

Comment: @JuanSanchez implementing this kind of classes is always going to be a pain in the ass. In any way, why do you want to have a put method that accepts an key-pair of `Object` then? I

Comment: @Aris_Kortex i put an answerd to help you to put you more in context

Answer (score 0):

@Aris_Kortex well firts of all, VO is used a LOT, to create the UImodel of this application and the constructor of VO is this:

```
public VO (Map<String,String> map)
   {
    this();
    Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Object key = it.next().toString();
        Object value = map.get(key);
        put (key, value);
    }
}   //  VO

/** Base SerVersion */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8683452581122892189L;

/** Keys            */
private ArrayList<String>   m_keys;
/** Values          */
private ArrayList<String>   m_values;
/** Embedded VOs    */
protected ArrayList<VO>     p_vos = null;
```

then i am affraid i can't measure the impact of changing something here...i need to create a package of this proyect that i refactoriced because before was a mess..but maven throw me that error...